# How to share a variable value between two extensions in IOS using swift without using Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Lets say, I have two extensions in a project. And I want to set a variable in one extension and read the updated value of that variable from another extension. I don't want to use Coredata.

Currently, I am using Common cocoa touch framework and imported that framework in both the extensions. I have defined getter and setter for one of the variable in the class defined in common framework. But, the changed value by one extension is not showing to another extension.

Any idea, why its not updating or anyother approach please.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you use NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() to store data in a single app.

In this case, you want to use ***App Groups*** to share data.

**Sharing NSUserDefaults data**

Add an App Group in your settings using the following steps:

1. In the Project Navigator click on the *.xcodeproj file (should be at the top).
2. To the right of the Project Navigator look for Project and Targets. Under targets click on your primary target (should be the first thing under Targets).
3. Towards the top, click on the Capabilities tab.
4. In the App Groups section click the switch to the right to turn App Groups ON.
5. Click on the + button and add an App Group named *group.com.company.myApp*.
6. Go to the same place in your other apps and this group should now be available to select. Turn this group on for each app that will be using this shared data.

*Note: If you go to the Apple Developer Portal (the Apple website that shows all of your Certificates, Identifiers, Devices and Provisioning Profiles) and go to Identifiers > App Groups you should see this new App Group.*

**Store data:**

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.company.myApp")
userDefaults!.setObject("user12345", forKey: "userId")
userDefaults!.synchronize()
```

**Retrieve data:**

```
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.company.myApp")
if let testUserId = userDefaults?.objectForKey("userId") as? String {
  print("User Id: \(testUserId)")
}
```

Comment: yeah..this is perfect